# Sign out button reloads all user controls

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, button, postback, pageload

I have an aspx page with several user controls (ascx) as well as an asp:button for signing out.

The click event of the button clears the session and does a response.redirect to the login page.

However, before the click event is called, since the page posts back, all of the Page_Load events run for all of the controls.

What is the best way to have the click event code run without unnecessary reloading of all user controls?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
```

around your control initialization in `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your logout button a link to a logout page that performs the session clear on page_load rather than it being a postback. That way the underlying page will never have to re-load.